# Rails: Dynamically build array from inherited controllers method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

I'm building an CMS as a subset of gems, all inheriting from the Base gem. Each gem provides different functionality, i.e. blog, pages, events, etc. I want to setup my Base gem so that it can dynamically build a Navigation based on the installed gems. I don't want to automatically do this by finding all the controllers/routes, I'd rather have each gem identify the navigation items an Array of Hashes, i.e.:

```
# In my Admin controller (from which all other gem controllers inherit)
@admin_navigation = [{controller: "users", label: "Users", sort_order: 10}, {controller: "settings", label: "Settings", sort_order: 11}]

# In my Pages gem
@admin_navigation += [{controller: "pages", label: "Pages", sort_order: 3}, {controller: "page_templates", label: "Pagetemplates", sort_order: 8}]

# In my blog gem
@admin_navigation += [{controller: "posts", label: "Blog", sort_order: 4}, {controller: "tags", label: "Tags", sort_order: 5}]
```

Basically I want my @admin_navigation variable to include all of the navigation items from each inherited controller. Is there a way for a controller to call a method from each inherited controller?

Is there a better way to accomplish this? In the end, I just need an array of these navigation item hashes to build my menu. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ruby `inherited` method for classes. So within your `AdminController`, you would

```
def self.inherited(subclass)
  @admin_navigation ||= []
  @admin_navigation += subclass.admin_navigation
end
```

Assuming that `@admin_navigation` is exposed as a class method on your inheriting controllers. You would also have to make sure that `AdminController` is defined first and after that all controllers are truely loaded afterwards, so that they trigger the callback.